# Prevent or change direction of animation in NCWidgetListViewController

Tags: xcode, swift

I am trying to create a Today Widget in Swift with XCode. I started with the available example code of XCode, when you create a new Today Widget target. The content of my Today widget is loaded from an external source, and whenever a new item appears in the external source it is added to the widget on refresh (`widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler`).

The only thing that bugs me is that new items automatically slide in from the top, overlapping all previous items and finally reaching the final destination at the bottom of the list. How can I change this behavior to either slide in from the bottom or not at all and just appear without sliding. I think I know how I could do my own animation with `...view.animator()...` but the original functionality is nowhere to be found in my code and I can't figure out how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

By now I'm pretty sure where it comes from. I assume the list items `NSView` is initiated with `NSViewControllerTransitionOptions` and the `SlideDown` option activated. So the animation comes from the views `NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator`. Unfortunately `presentViewController` is not called by myself. This probably is somewhere in the internals of `NCWidgetListViewDelegate`, which has no option to prevent or change the animation. So I guess, the only way how to "fix" this is to drop `NCWidgetListViewDelegate` completely and start from scratch. So the answer would be: **It's not possible.**